# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'vread'

Tags: python

Using anaconda 2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04.
after importing skvideo successfully.
and I run the code

```
import skvideo.io
import skvideo.io as vio
```

its gives error of:

```
"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'vread'"
```

the code i run and output/error is in image given below.

Comment: There isn't an image in your post.

Answer (score 1):

I had initially installed skvideo using
`pip install scikit-video`
and was facing the same error.

It vanished after I installed as follows:

`pip install sk-video`

Answer (score 0):

Please just try `pip install scikit-video` which will install a new package *scikit_video-.whl*.